# psql: symbol lookup error: psql: undefined symbol: PQsetErrorContextVisibility

Tags: postgresql, centos7, postgresql-9.2, postgres-9.6

I switched my postgres version from 9.2.24 to 9.6 because I need jsonb compatibility along with other recent features. I am running a vm on centos 7.

I decided to wipe all existing instances of postgres (which are almost empty since it is staging) and then installed 9.6. However, once I enter the postgres shell I received the following error when I type `psql`:

`psql: symbol lookup error: psql: undefined symbol: PQsetErrorContextVisibility`

I assume I need to change the path that psql is looking for so that it connects properly but I am not sure where to point it.

Note: `ls` reveals 2 directories and 1 file in postgres bash `9.6 data and initdb.log`.

Comment: try `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib64/`

Comment: @VaoTsun, this was the solution for me. The libpq.so shared library was located in /usr/lib64. Adding this path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH and running ldconfig did the trick.

Comment: Isn't the location /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5? (reference https://packages.debian.org/stretch/amd64/libpq5/filelist)

Comment: Hi @senfo and all could you please help me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76272014/error-initdb-failed-postgresql-update-from-13-6-to-15-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> psql: symbol lookup error: psql: undefined symbol: PQsetErrorContextVisibility

That means your copy of `psql` is looking for a dynamic symbol in `libpq.so` which the version in your path does not have.

Do you have a custom compiled version of `psql`? And, if so, you'll have to build it against the newer libpq that 9.6 provides.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:<your postgres lib directory>
```

For example

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib64/
```

(turning @vaotsun's comment into an answer)

Answer (score 1):

Just faced this because of red hat SCL.
I got away with the following.

> ln -s /opt/rh/rh-postgresql96/root/usr/lib64/libpq.so.rh-postgresql96-5.9 /opt/rh/rh-postgresql96/root/usr/lib64/libpq.so.5
>
> ln -s /opt/rh/rh-postgresql96/root/usr/lib64/libpq.so.5 /usr/lib/libpq.so.5

In wouldn't advise my worst enemy about using software coming from SCL repository in place of an external repo (see postgresql 96 on centos 7).

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @interestedparty333.
You can find the exact missing lib and add the folder to LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Example:

```
find ~+ -name libpq.so.5
```

It can give a result like below (~+ gives absolute path as a result of find):

```
/home/myuser/postgresql-12.9/src/interfaces/libpq/libpq.so.5
```

So you can add a folder (absolute path) to LD_LIBRARY_PATH like:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/myuser/postgresql-12.9/src/interfaces/libpq/
```

Now psql should work OK.
In case you would need additional lib, find&add like above for every missing one.