# Getting symbol lookup error for psql while running psql command

Tags: postgresql, redhat, psql

I am getting issue as -

```
psql: symbol lookup error: psql: undefined symbol: PQsetErrorContextVisibility
```

I also followed the link - [psql: symbol lookup error: psql: undefined symbol: PQsetErrorContextVisibility](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52303275/14048308)

But was not able to solve that issue.

Command which I tried -

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/pgsql_12/lib
```

And also looked for -

```
rpm -qa|grep postgresql
postgresql-libs-9.2.24-4.el7_8.x86_64
postgresql12-libs-12.3-5PGDG.rhel7.x86_64
postgresql11-libs-11.9-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64
spacewalk-postgresql-clean-2.7.4-1.0.1.el7.noarch
postgresql12-contrib-12.3-5PGDG.rhel7.x86_64
postgresql12-12.3-5PGDG.rhel7.x86_64
postgresql12-devel-12.3-5PGDG.rhel7.x86_64
postgresql12-server-12.3-5PGDG.rhel7.x86_64
```

Can someone please help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function was introduced in `libpq` in 9.5, so your `psql` from v12 must by mistake try to load the `libpq` from version 9.2, which causes this linker error.

You can try to change your shared library search path so that doesn't happen, but usually the better solution is to remove the 9.2 installation. The operating system packages and the PGDG packages don't work together well.